# I2P.SE still shows up in the Update profile info site list

Tags: bug, network-profile

If you go to your network profile https://stackexchange.com/users/current click the "Update profile info" button and then scroll down you will see [I2P.SE](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/99297) is listed a site that has been closed for over a year now.

[image]

<sub>I couldn't take a screenshot of the drop down list itself.</sub>

It's not a major problem but it seems unnecessarily to be on the list. Should it be removed?

Comment: All of the closed sites are still in the list if you had a profile there. I think it's just an effect of the way that list is generated. As an aside, I'd rather see the bio and other profile information disappear from the network profile altogether, and leave that stuff to site profiles only. Would solve a lot of annoying problems that no one wants to fix.

Comment: @animuson Oh so not everybody will see it?

Comment: No. You only ever see sites where you have a profile (or had in this case I guess). E.g. I also see the Arabic Language site in the list which was also closed long ago.