# Close x in update profile info dialogue not centered

Tags: bug, design, stackexchange.com, network-profile

In the network profile if you choose *Update profile info* the close button doesn't have the X centered inside the circle. I've found older posts where this happens with a [different misalignment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/303662/665544).

[image: update profile info dialogue]

Using Windows 10, Firefox 102.0.1 (64-bit), 1920x1080. rev 2022.7.19.42626